# Texture wrong value in fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm loading a custom data into 2D texture GL_RGBA16F:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
int Gx = 128;
int Gy = 128;
GLuint grammar;
glGenTextures(1, &grammar);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grammar);
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA16F, Gx, Gy);

float* grammardata = new float[Gx * Gy * 4](); // set default to zero

*(grammardata) = 1; 

glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,Gx,Gy,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,grammardata);

int grammarloc = glGetUniformLocation(p_myGLSL->getProgramID(), "grammar");
if (grammarloc < 0) {
    printf("grammar missing!\n");
    exit(0);
}

glUniform1i(grammarloc, 0);
```

When I read the value of uniform sampler2D grammar in GLSL, it returns 0.25 instead of 1. How do I fix the scaling problem?

```
if (texture(grammar, vec2(0,0) == 0.25) {
    FragColor = vec4(0,1,0,1);
} else
{
    FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

Comment: Do you somewhere set the GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER/GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER? By default MIN_FILTER is set to GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR, which would interpolate between mipmap levels. Since you are not generating mipmaps, this might lead to 0.25.

Comment: YES, that's the error. Thank you! Btw how does it interpolate even if I'm reading from (0,0) location?

Comment: I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default texture interpolation is set to the following values:

```
GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER = GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR,
GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER = GL_LINEAR
GL_WRAP[R|S|T] = GL_REPEAT
```

This means, in cases where the mapping between texels of the texture and pixels on the screen does not fit, the hardware interpolates will interpolate for you. There can be two cases:

- The texture is displayed smaller than it actually is: In this case interpolation is performed between two mipmap levels. If no mipmaps are generated, these are treated as beeing 0, which could lead to 0.25.
- The texture is displayed larger than it actually is (and I think this will be the case here): Here, the hardware does not interpolate between mipmap levels, but between adjacent texels in the texture. The problem now comes from the fact, that (0,0) in texture coordinates is **NOT** the center of pixel [0,0], but the lower left corner of it.

Have a look at the following drawing, which illustrates how texture coordinates are defined (here with 4 texels)

```
tex-coord:   0          0.25        0.5         0.75         1
texels       |-----0-----|-----1-----|-----2-----|-----3-----|
```

As you can see, 0 is on the boundary of a texel, while the first texels center is at (1/(2 * |texels|)).

This means for you, that with wrap mode set to GL_REPEAT, texture coordinate (0,0) will interpolate uniformly between the texels [0,0], [-1,0], [-1,-1], [0,-1]. Since `-1 == 127` (due to repeat) and everything except [0,0] is 0, this results in

```
([0,0] + [-1,0] + [-1,-1] + [0,-1]) / 4 =
   1   +    0   +    0    +   0   ) / 4 = 0.25
```

Comment: How do I access to the grammardata index in the shader? I.E. get the value grammardata[1,0,3] for example?

Comment: Where does the 3rd coordinate come from? Do you mean the mipmap?

Comment: grammardata is a RGBA texture (128x128x4). There is no mipmap here.

Comment: So 3 means alpha channel? Basically you can use `texelFetch(grammardata, ivec2(1,0), 0).a`